# Javascript Mobile Keyboard Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, keyboard

I am making a keyboard that recognizes hate language/cuss words and shows a alert if they type one. I currently have a working keyboard. The buttons that the user clicks is put into a textarea. I  have used Javascript, HTML, CSS, and some JQuery to speed things up. To recognize words the user types, I know I need to use the addEventListener code and a touch event but I do not know how to implement it.

```js
$(function() {
  var $write = $('#write'),
    shift = false,
    capslock = false; //DONE

  $('#keyboard li').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      character = $this.html(); // If it's a lowercase letter, nothing happens to this variable //DONE

    // Shift keys
    if ($this.hasClass('left-shift') || $this.hasClass('right-shift')) {
      $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
      $('.symbol span').toggle();

      shift = (shift === true) ? false : true;
      capslock = false;
      return false;
    } //DONE

    // Caps lock
    if ($this.hasClass('capslock')) {
      $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
      capslock = true;
      return false; //DONE
    }

    // Delete
    if ($this.hasClass('delete')) {
      var html = $write.val();

      $write.val(html.substr(0, html.length - 1));
      return false;
    } //DONE

    // Special characters
    if ($this.hasClass('symbol')) character = $('span:visible', $this).html();
    if ($this.hasClass('space')) character = ' ';
    if ($this.hasClass('tab')) character = "\t";
    if ($this.hasClass('return')) character = "\n";
    //DONE
    // Uppercase letter
    if ($this.hasClass('uppercase')) character = character.toUpperCase();
    //DONE
    // Remove shift once a key is clicked.
    if (shift === true) {
      $('.symbol span').toggle();
      if (capslock === false) $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');

      shift = false;
    }
    console.log("DO IT ", character);
    // Add the character
    $write.val($write.val() + character);
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font: 71%/1.5 Verdana, Sans-Serif;
  background: DodgerBlue;
}

#container {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 688px;
}

#write {
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 671px;
  height: 200px;
  font: 1em/1.5 Verdana, Sans-Serif;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #f9f9f9;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

#keyboard {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#keyboard li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background: DogerBlue;
  border: 1px solid #f9f9f9;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.capslock,
.tab,
.left-shift {
  clear: left;
}

#keyboard .tab,
#keyboard .delete {
  width: 70px;
}

#keyboard .capslock {
  width: 80px;
}

#keyboard .return {
  width: 77px;
  color: Orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

  <title>Online Keyboard</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">
    <textarea id="write" rows="6" cols="60"></textarea>
    <ul id="keyboard">
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">`</span><span class="on">~</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">1</span><span class="on">!</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">2</span><span class="on">@</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">3</span><span class="on">#</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">4</span><span class="on">$</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">5</span><span class="on">%</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">6</span><span class="on">^</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">7</span><span class="on">&amp;</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">8</span><span class="on">*</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">9</span><span class="on">(</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">0</span><span class="on">)</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">-</span><span class="on">_</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">=</span><span class="on">+</span></li>
      <li class="delete lastitem">delete</li>
      <li class="tab">tab</li>
      <li class="letter">q</li>
      <li class="letter">w</li>
      <li class="letter">e</li>
      <li class="letter">r</li>
      <li class="letter">t</li>
      <li class="letter">y</li>
      <li class="letter">u</li>
      <li class="letter">i</li>
      <li class="letter">o</li>
      <li class="letter">p</li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">[</span><span class="on">{</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">]</span><span class="on">}</span></li>
      <li class="symbol lastitem"><span class="off">\</span><span class="on">|</span></li>
      <li class="capslock">caps lock</li>
      <li class="letter">a</li>
      <li class="letter">s</li>
      <li class="letter">d</li>
      <li class="letter">f</li>
      <li class="letter">g</li>
      <li class="letter">h</li>
      <li class="letter">j</li>
      <li class="letter">k</li>
      <li class="letter">l</li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">;</span><span class="on">:</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">'</span><span class="on">&quot;</span></li>
      <li class="return lastitem">return</li>
      <li class="left-shift">shift</li>
      <li class="letter">z</li>
      <li class="letter">x</li>
      <li class="letter">c</li>
      <li class="letter">v</li>
      <li class="letter">b</li>
      <li class="letter">n</li>
      <li class="letter">m</li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">,</span><span class="on">&lt;</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">.</span><span class="on">&gt;</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">/</span><span class="on">?</span></li>
      <li class="right-shift lastitem">shift</li>
      <li class="space lastitem">&nbsp;</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="keyboard.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To validate each typed word you need to capture the input (which your example already does) and capture the last typed word. To do so, we assume words are separated by spaces and then validate the last word against a dictionary, here are the relevant parts:

```
var isValidWord = function(word) {
  // update the following variable with all the invalid words
  var invalidWords = ['foo', 'bar'];
  return !invalidWords.find(function(invalid) {
    return word === invalid;
  });
};

var inputText = $write.val() + character;
var words = inputText.split(' ');
var lastWord = words[words.length - 1]
if (isValidWord(lastWord)) {
  $write.val(inputText);
} else {
  alert('Error: Please choose a different word')
}
```

And the a complete example, try to type `foo` or `bar` and you will get an alert message:

```js
$(function() {

  var isValidWord = function(word) {
    var invalidWords = ['foo', 'bar'];
    return !invalidWords.find(function(invalid) {
      return word === invalid;
    });
  };
  var $write = $('#write'),
    shift = false,
    capslock = false; //DONE

  $('#keyboard li').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      character = $this.html(); // If it's a lowercase letter, nothing happens to this variable //DONE

    // Shift keys
    if ($this.hasClass('left-shift') || $this.hasClass('right-shift')) {
      $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
      $('.symbol span').toggle();

      shift = (shift === true) ? false : true;
      capslock = false;
      return false;
    } //DONE

    // Caps lock
    if ($this.hasClass('capslock')) {
      $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');
      capslock = true;
      return false; //DONE
    }

    // Delete
    if ($this.hasClass('delete')) {
      var html = $write.val();

      $write.val(html.substr(0, html.length - 1));
      return false;
    } //DONE

    // Special characters
    if ($this.hasClass('symbol')) character = $('span:visible', $this).html();
    if ($this.hasClass('space')) character = ' ';
    if ($this.hasClass('tab')) character = "\t";
    if ($this.hasClass('return')) character = "\n";
    //DONE
    // Uppercase letter
    if ($this.hasClass('uppercase')) character = character.toUpperCase();
    //DONE
    // Remove shift once a key is clicked.
    if (shift === true) {
      $('.symbol span').toggle();
      if (capslock === false) $('.letter').toggleClass('uppercase');

      shift = false;
    }
    var inputText = $write.val() + character;
    var words = inputText.split(' ');
    var lastWord = words[words.length - 1]
    if (isValidWord(lastWord)) {
      $write.val(inputText);
    } else {
      alert('Error: Please choose a different word')
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font: 71%/1.5 Verdana, Sans-Serif;
  background: DodgerBlue;
}

#container {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 688px;
}

#write {
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 671px;
  height: 200px;
  font: 1em/1.5 Verdana, Sans-Serif;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #f9f9f9;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

#keyboard {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#keyboard li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background: DogerBlue;
  border: 1px solid #f9f9f9;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.capslock,
.tab,
.left-shift {
  clear: left;
}

#keyboard .tab,
#keyboard .delete {
  width: 70px;
}

#keyboard .capslock {
  width: 80px;
}

#keyboard .return {
  width: 77px;
  color: Orange;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Online Keyboard</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <textarea id="write" rows="6" cols="60"></textarea>
    <ul id="keyboard">
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">`</span><span class="on">~</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">1</span><span class="on">!</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">2</span><span class="on">@</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">3</span><span class="on">#</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">4</span><span class="on">$</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">5</span><span class="on">%</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">6</span><span class="on">^</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">7</span><span class="on">&amp;</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">8</span><span class="on">*</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">9</span><span class="on">(</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">0</span><span class="on">)</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">-</span><span class="on">_</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">=</span><span class="on">+</span></li>
      <li class="delete lastitem">delete</li>
      <li class="tab">tab</li>
      <li class="letter">q</li>
      <li class="letter">w</li>
      <li class="letter">e</li>
      <li class="letter">r</li>
      <li class="letter">t</li>
      <li class="letter">y</li>
      <li class="letter">u</li>
      <li class="letter">i</li>
      <li class="letter">o</li>
      <li class="letter">p</li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">[</span><span class="on">{</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">]</span><span class="on">}</span></li>
      <li class="symbol lastitem"><span class="off">\</span><span class="on">|</span></li>
      <li class="capslock">caps lock</li>
      <li class="letter">a</li>
      <li class="letter">s</li>
      <li class="letter">d</li>
      <li class="letter">f</li>
      <li class="letter">g</li>
      <li class="letter">h</li>
      <li class="letter">j</li>
      <li class="letter">k</li>
      <li class="letter">l</li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">;</span><span class="on">:</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">'</span><span class="on">&quot;</span></li>
      <li class="return lastitem">return</li>
      <li class="left-shift">shift</li>
      <li class="letter">z</li>
      <li class="letter">x</li>
      <li class="letter">c</li>
      <li class="letter">v</li>
      <li class="letter">b</li>
      <li class="letter">n</li>
      <li class="letter">m</li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">,</span><span class="on">&lt;</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">.</span><span class="on">&gt;</span></li>
      <li class="symbol"><span class="off">/</span><span class="on">?</span></li>
      <li class="right-shift lastitem">shift</li>
      <li class="space lastitem">&nbsp;</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="keyboard.js"></script>
</body>
```